# Openlayers feature alignment with map displayed in an iframe in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, openlayers

I have an Openlayers 2.11 map displayed in an Iframe. It works fine in IE and Firefox. In Chrome the layers are misaligned. This is easily reproduced with the Openlayers examples.
Create an aspx page like this (below).
Once loaded, pan the map by dragging. It behaves as expected in IE and Firefox. In Chrome, the layer moves independently.
This happens regardless of whether I set sphericalMercator=true on the layer (I have the example locally).
If the example is NOT in an Iframe, then it works correctly.
It is important that I can run the map in an Iframe.

Any advice appreciated.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div style="float:right;width:800px;height:600px">
        <iframe runat="server" frameborder="0" src="http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/vector-features.html" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like this might be due to a bug in Chrome 15. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=102011

Answer (score 1):

The problem is described here:

http://code.google.com/p/ala-citizenscience/issues/detail?id=6

The solution is to have your own version of OpenLayers with some minor changes (jQuery is required):
Search for:

```
renderers:['SVG','VML','Canvas']
```

and change it for:

```
renderers:(jQuery.browser.webkit?['Canvas','VML']:['SVG','Canvas','VML'])
```

(If OpenLayer's code is minimized, this is a part of a long line with multiple instructions)

---

If you use OpenLayers images and style and you want to keep them, you should change also:

**if OpenLayers 2.11:**

```
return(function(){return l;})
```

with

```
return(function(){return "http://www.openlayers.org/api/";})
```

**if OpenLayers 2.10:**

```
var scriptLocation;
```

with

```
var scriptLocation = "http://www.openlayers.org/api/";
```